# Kibana: infinite extent for field infinity-infinity

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, altair, vega-lite, vega

I decided to use the suggestion on this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-jupyter-notebook-visualizations-kibana-dashboards-vega-data-science) that suggest to create panel of vega with altair. Everything works fine except for the warning. I've tried to remove warnings on setting advance but I dindn't mange to solve. In order to save the chart I use the routines on this [link](https://github.com/walterra/jupyter2kibana/blob/master/kibana_vega_util.py). Every help will be appreciate. The problem as suggest in previous topics open is on data, (because the warning is refer to @timestamp and another date field.
I would like to hide the warning in order to work without it, maybe is it possible inserting a script on the routines on 2 links in order to add the script in this [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/infinite-extent-for-field-count-infinity-infinity/276333/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
chart_json['config']['kibana']={'hideWarnings': true}
```